# Transformations.map LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I have following code :

```
val liveData = MutableLiveData<String>()
liveData.value = "Ali"

val res = map(liveData) { post(it) }
textview.text = res.value.toString()


fun post(name: String): String {
     return "$name $name"
}
```

I expect it to print `Ali Ali` but it prints a null value. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LiveData` works asynchronously. The value you've set for it isn't immediately available in the transformed `LiveData`. Instead of trying to read that value directly, you should `observe` its changes, then you'll get the latest values:

```
res.observe(this, Observer { name ->
     textview.text = name
})
```

(This code sample assumes that `this` is a `LifecyleOwner`, such as an `AppCompatActivity`.)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a null check.

`res.value.toString()` 
Imagine the case when res.value is null you are doing this.

`null.toString()` which the result is the string "null"

And the other hand, when you use LiveData the right approach is to observe all changes like zsmb13 suggested.

`res.observe(this, Observer { name ->
     textview.text = name
})`